# how to create a zendesk ticket with inline image

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I would like to create a ticket with inline image but cannot get through it. I am using a rich text having a pasted screen capture image, the content is like

```
"<img ..."
```

By using ZendeskApi_V2, I set the Ticket's Comment HtmlBody with the content mentioned but did not work, neither of PlainBody or Body.

Anyone can help, please.

For instance:

In my application, an image is inserted into a RadEditor

[image]

By setting the Ticket.Comment as

```
var ticket = new Ticket {
    Comment = new Comment {
        HtmlBody = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(RadEditor.Content)
    }
}
```

After sending the Create Ticket request, I cannot see the inline image in the Zendesk dashboard.

So, did I do it in a right way? How should an embedded or inline image be sent through Zendesk API?

Comment: Seeing the actual request that you're making, or perhaps the code that you're using to make the request, would help people to better understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks jpalmieri. I have updated the question with more detail. My purpose is to ask for a right way to send a ticket with an inline image, not an attachment image.

Comment: @JamesRao did you solve it? If so, could you share the code in a new answer, please?

Comment: @ilCosmico it's being a while. i cannot remember precisely, but can you pls try Jimmy Long method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to upload the attachment file first, then you can set the attachment's token in the comment.  See here - https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/tickets#attaching-files

Comment: Here is the updated link: https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/managing-tickets/creating-and-updating-tickets/#attaching-files